# How to defer reading until writing is done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a multiplayer game using node.js, socket.io and MongoDB.

When a player die they can reload the browser just before the fatal hit and still be alive even though the kill was registered. I'm using the following solution to save/load a player:

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', onSocketConnection);

function onSocketConnection(client) {
    util.log('New player has connected: '+client.id);

    client.on('new player', function() {
        db.collection('players').findOne({uuid: uid}, function(err, data) {
            var player = new Player(data);
            players.push(player);
        });
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        db.collection('players').update({uuid: player.uuid}, {$set: player}, {w: 1}, function(err, result) {
            console.log('player written');
        }); 
    });
};
```

What I think happens is that the "disconnect" event starts writing but before it is done the "new player" event fires, loads the player from the database and initializes it again. So the read happens before the write is done (meaning they will get the state of the player from the disconnect prior the one happening right now).

Is this the problem? If not, is there anything else in my approach that can cause this? If this is indeed the problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: can you find and kill them from the disconnect update callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multiplayer game, you need to do important state logic on the server, or at least do some sort of state validation on the server side.

You are only noticing this "hack" because it is easy to do. You have to design your multiplayer server to be resistant against someone who is experienced at writing their own client with socket.io. Basically, this means that you shouldn't automatically trust important data coming from any client.

In your situation, you need to send a request at the earliest point-of-no-return before a death. This will probably prevent most individuals form performing this exploit, but anyone who knows some javascript and has chrome will be able to prevent that request from being sent.